# How to open any Activity using notification when app is not running in Background?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

This is my Firbase Service code i just want to open an Another Acivity when app is closed or not running in background i done Everything but it wont work please help

```
private void createNotification(String messageBody, String title, RemoteMessage message)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,NotificationScreen.class);
    intent.putExtra("type",message.getData().get("json"));
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent resultIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( this ,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    Uri notificationSoundURI = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mNotificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder( this)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(),R.drawable.icon))
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(notificationSoundURI)
            .setContentIntent(resultIntent);
    mNotificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon(mNotificationBuilder));
    //Log.i("data",map.values().toString());
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, mNotificationBuilder.build());
}
private int getNotificationIcon(NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder) {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        int color = 0x008000;
        notificationBuilder.setColor(color);
        return R.drawable.icon;

    }
    return R.drawable.icon;
}
```

Already applied xml code

```
<activity android:name=".NotificationScreen"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="NotificationScreen" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Please help unable to understand ..

Comment: What do you mean by not working?

Comment: Is there any error? If it has, can you share the errors you have encountered?

Comment: Sorry but no errors are encountered and not working means when i am clicking  on notification its not opening the NotificationScreen(Target Activity) class its taking me to my launcher screen(This error only happen when app is not in the background)

Answer (score 0):

For Android, you could simply set the value of `click_action` parameter in your `notification` payload equal to the intent filter of the corresponding activity that you want to open. As mentioned in the docs (emphasis mine):

> The action associated with a user click on the notification.
>
> **If specified, an activity with a matching intent filter is launched when a user clicks on the notification**.

So for example you have this payload:

```
{
  "to": <TOKEN>,
  "notification": {
    ...
    "click_action" : "OPEN_ME"
    ...
  }
}
```

Then you have an Activity in your manifest that has the corresponding intent-filter name (similar to your post):

```
   <activity android:name=".NotificationScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="OPEN_ME" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

It should open that specific activity.

Comment: thank you very much but its not the case like this firbase updated the lib and in updated lib you get all paylod on launcher screen in as a intent extra so you can data from there thank you very much again

Comment: That's the default behavior. But if you specify `click_action` parameter, it should work like what I mentioned above. If you managed to make it work on your own, feel free to post an answer as well. Stack Overflow promotes self-answer of posts if possible. Cheers!